# Django query set select multiple columns and get instance object in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following code to get selected columns in Django

```
>>> l = Listing.objects.values("id", "City")[:10]
>>> l
[{'City': u'GLENN DALE', 'id': 1459}, {'City': u'SHADY SIDE', 'id': 1460}, {'City': u'BALTIMORE', 'id': 1474}, {'City': u'BALTIMORE', 'id': 1463}, {'City': u'EDGEWOOD', 'id': 1464}, {'City': u'CAPITOL HEIGHTS', 'id': 1466}, {'City': u'ROCK HALL', 'id': 1465}, {'City': u'RIVA', 'id': 1468}, {'City': u'PRINCE FREDERICK', 'id': 1469}, {'City': u'FREDERICK', 'id': 1470}]
>>>
```

If I pass the "l" object to the template, I will have a list of dictionary. However, I have a function that's attached to the Listing model, and need it call it from the template.

The following will output nothing, how do I get back to the object?

```
{% for obj in l %}
   {{obj.get_images}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why don't you add images to your values query?

Comment: Or why don't you just query for the Listings objects, rather than using `values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `only` instead of `values` like:

```
l = Listing.objects.only("id", "City")[:10]
```

Get more info about `only` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#only)